# Netbeans: change package location without moving files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netbeans

I have a netbeans project with directories like:

```
Top
  - pom.xml
  - src
     |
      - main
         | 
          - java 
              |
               - com
                   | 
                     - foo
                         |
                           - bar 
                                A.java
                                B.java
```

The package designation for A.java then is:

```
 package main.com.foo.bar
```

Where netbeans is using the toplevel directory as the source, and reading the pom.xml file to bring in maven dependencies.

My colleagues are developing in Eclipse, and their package headers are

```
package com.foo.bar
```

Is it possible to somehow specify to netbeans that the com folder should be recognized as the top-level directory for the source files, but retain the location of pom.xml?  They were able to implement such packaging in Eclipse by specifying the source directory as com, somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Maven is about, defaults and some established conventions. The structure is .

src / main / java / com / foo / bar

You are missing the java sub-folder. If you add it then automatically all the IDE's that properly support and use Maven will import your code properly.

Please have a look if you have some spare time to the [standard maven layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry, I do have the java folder, I misttyped the question.  However, when it's laid out standard like that, then my package headers are:

      `main.java.com.foo.bar`

However, the rest of the project specifies them as `com.foo.bar`

Comment: Hi, correct all the packages (that either you or the IDE must have edited) to the expected value meaning package com.foo.bar; Then I would suggest you delete any created IDE specific files (generated after you imported or started the project) and reimport the project . It should be ok :)

Comment: You can do a global search for package main.java.com.foo.bar; and replace it with package com.foo.bar; ;)

Comment: Is this different from a refactor?  Because if I simply refactor the package to com.foo.bar, it moves the files on my harddrive

Comment: if the files are on the correct - 'expected' folder , then just do a text search replace and NOT refactor

Comment: Nah, doesn't work.  All files now have an incorrect package error.

Comment: Make sure the packages are correct again and re-import the project.